# Unknown encoding Node.js Net/TCP

Tags: node.js, tcp

I am trying to send a message using node.js net

I keep getting an error event with strings:

```
buffer.js:377
  throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
        ^
TypeError: Unknown encoding: foobarstringfoobarstringfoobarstringfoobarstring
    at Buffer.write (buffer.js:377:13)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:215:28)
    at createWriteReq (net.js:675:33)
    at Socket._write (net.js:640:18)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:219:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:209:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:613:40)
    at someModule.<anonymous> (/home/engine/private_js/N.cs.js:120:43)
    at someModule.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Must I **JSON.stringify** and **JSON.parse**?

First I net.createServer() ...

```
var net=require('net');
var server=net.createServer(function(push){
    someModule.on('eventA',function(A,B,OBJ){
        push.write('eventA',{'A':A,'B':B,'OBJ':OBJ},'utf-8');
        });
    someModule.on('eventX',function(str){
        push.write('eventX',str,'utf-8');
        });
    push.on('error',function(err){
        console.dir(err);
        });
    });
server.listen(8005,function(){});
```

... then I net.connect() to the server ...

```
var net=require('net');
var pull=new net.Socket();
pull.connect(8005,'127.0.0.1',function(){
    pull.on('eventA',function(_){
        eventA(_.A,_.B,_.OBJ);
        });
    pull.on('eventX',function(str){
        eventX(str);
        });
    pull.on('error',function(err){
        console.dir(err);
        });
    });
```

... and pass data into ordinary functions

```
function eventA(A,B,OBJ){
    //run some code
    };

function eventX(str){
    //run some code
    };
```

Why does it error even with a string? Is it not meant for objects??

Answer (score 0):

Write to a socket looks like this: `socket.write(data[, encoding][, callback])`. The encoding should be `utf8`, not `utf-8`.